# Python data descriptor not working

Tags: python

I have this code for testing the data descriptors

```
class DataDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1990

    def __get__(self,obj,cls):
        print "__get__ in Data descriptor"
        return self.value

    def __set__(self,obj,value):
        self.obj = value
        print "__set__ in Non Data Descriptor"

    def __del__(self,obj):
        print "__del__ in Non Data Descriptor"
        del self.obj

class NonDataDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self,obj,cls):
        print "__get__ in Non Data descriptor"


class C(object):
    dd = DataDescriptor()
    ndd =NonDataDescriptor()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 1

cobj = C()
cobj.dd
```

When i execute that , then i ca only see the print statement but i can't see the actual value i am retirung in my get function

My output is this only

```
__get__ in Data descriptor
```

Comment: you should do `print cobj.dd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't print the return value. So, you didn't see it.

You need to do: -

```
print cobj.dd
```

Comment: but then how did the other staement get printed

Comment: @user2024264. That you are printing inside the function itself right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def __get__(self, obj, cls):
    print "__get__ in Data descriptor", self.value
    return self.value
```

See the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example)